# babel.config.js babel eslint turn off / disable a rule

Tags: vue.js, eslint, babel-eslint

I would like to deactivate a babel eslint rule `no-unused-vars`.

if using to eslint (not babel-eslint) I would add the following

`.eslintrc.js`

```
 rules: {
    'no-unused-vars': 'off'
  }
```

So I tried adding the same code to

`babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
 ],
  rules: {
   'no-unused-vars': 'off'
 }
}
```

but this generates an error

```
 ERROR  ReferenceError: Unknown option: .rules. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
```

I can find no mention of [rules](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options) in the docs. I tried `exclude` but that did not work in disabling the rule.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a `"eslintConfig"` section to my package.json and it was respected by my linter running on every build.

I might suggest adding your rules there.

You might need to change some plugins or other configs, but I removed those from the snippet to cut down on the size.

```
"eslintConfig": {
        [... removed for brevity]
        "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
        "rules": {
            "no-unused-vars": "off"
        }
    },
```